# Add hyperlink to gridview programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a gridview and need to add controls to header row. I am able to add text, but how can I add a hyperlink to the header row.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            GridView HeaderGrid = (GridView)sender;
            GridViewRow HeaderGridRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Insert);
            TableCell HeaderCell = new TableCell();

            HeaderCell.Text = "Logistics Details";
            HeaderCell.ColumnSpan = 2;
            HeaderGridRow.Cells.Add(HeaderCell);
            GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, HeaderGridRow);

            HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
            hl.ID = "hlDetail";
            hl.Text = "Details";
            //the below line doesn't add controls
            HeaderGridRow.Controls.Add(hl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to add the control to a specific Cell within the row, e.g.

```
HeaderGridRow.Cells[0].Controls.Add(hl);
```

Since it's a grid, it's not logical for items to exist within a row outside a cell - then there is no way to know where exactly to display it.

You probably also need to set the `NavigateUrl` property of the Hyperlink, otherwise it does not know where to navigate e.g.

```
hl.NavigateURL = "https://www.google.com"
```